# How do I calculate a voltage divider with an offset

Tags: voltage-divider, dc-offset

I've got the following circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fvwWRk.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

By running the simulation I can see that a signal voltage of 3.13 converts to an output of 2.14, but I'm not sure how it got that.

If I simply use the voltage divider and subtract out the 1.7 reference voltage, I get:

$$ 3.13 \times \frac{10}{(22+10)}-1.7 = -0.7218 $$

What am I doing wrong? Btw, software engineer not electrical engineer, so I'm sure this is a noob question.

Comment: You should subtract `1.7` from `3.13`, not from the whole expression.

Comment: @EugeneSh. that yields .44 though

Comment: Right, because then you need to add it, because you want both, the voltage drop on R2 and V1 for the the Vout. Better yet use the superposition principle and solve for each source separately.

Comment: @EugeneSh. got it, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two different problem here.

1. The voltage divider formula applies to the voltage across the entire divider:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fgD2zs.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

$$
 V_2 = V_{tot} \cdot \frac{R2}{R1+R2}
$$

That is, Vtot is the voltage between nodes A and B.

2. To calculate Vtot you can use LKT and you obtain that:

$$
 V_{tot} = V_{sine} - V_1
$$

Those expressions are valid *for each instant*, so you can apply them in particular to the peak sine value, that you say is 3.13.

Therefore you get:

\$
V_{tot(peak)} = V_{sine(peak)} - V_1 = 3.13V - 1.7V = 1.43V
\$

\$
V_{2(peak)} = V_{tot(peak)} \cdot \frac{R2}{R1+R2} = 
1.43V \cdot \frac{100}{100+220} = 0.45V
\$

**EDIT** (to provide a complete solution, not only an hint)

Once you get \$V_{2(peak)}\$ you can get \$V_{out(peak)}\$ by adding \$V_1\$:

\$
V_{out(peak)} = V_{2(peak)} + V_1 = 0.45V + 1.7V = 2.15V
\$

Which is the result you get from simulation, within approximation errors.

Here is a plot of the various voltages using LTspice:

[image]

which derived from this circuit:

[image]

Comment: I appreciate you taking the time to explain this further, but neither of your answers add up to 2.14, so I'm a bit confused.

Comment: @MikeSchem I didn't give you a full solution. I thought the hints were enough for you to work out the rest for yourself. V2 is the voltage across R2. To get Vout, which is the voltage across the output terminal and ground, you must add V2 to V1. So you get 0.45 + 1.7 = 2.15V *peak* voltage (sorry for the slight calculation error in V2 computation - late night answer :-)).

Comment: Wow, thanks for going the extra mile!

Comment: quick follow up question if you don't mind.  Is this the best circuit to accurately measure the sine wave from a micro controller?  I've heard of other methods like using an op amp or a rectifier with a voltage divider, but not sure what's the best, for the highest level of accuracy.

Comment: @MikeSchem I'm not sure I follow you. Do you mean R1, R2 and V1 are components you would add between the sine wave and the MCU ADC to measure the sine wave? If this is what you meant, well, what you describe as V1 is not usually a battery or a voltage regulator. Indeed you would use an opamp to perform signal conditioning on the sinewave before feeding the output of the opamp circuit to the ADC. You could use an opamp wired as an inverting amplifier with an added offset. But this a whole different question.

Answer (score 3):

There are two different "voltages" you speak of.

1. The 6.26V peak-to-peak sine wave, centered around 0V.
2. The 1.7V DC offset voltage.

The output of the circuit is a sine wave, of a different amplitude, and with a different offset than the original one.

A nice way to analyze such a circuit is using **superposition** (look up superposition in circuit analysis!): separate out the DC and the AC part of the sine wave:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fwqG2Z.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The DC circuit can be re-drawn as follows, noting that a 0V voltage source is a short and can be replaced with a wire:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fOL1gy.png)</sup>

That should give you the DC part of the output voltage.

The AC part of the output voltage is already a simple divider circuit - we replace the 0V AC source V1 (it is DC, so 0V in AC!) with a wire, so you can tackle that with what you already know.

The output voltage will be the *sum* of the DC "offset" and the AC sine wave.

The DC offset is $$1.7{\rm\ V} {220{\rm k} \over 100{\rm k}+220{\rm k}}.$$

The AC amplitude is $$3.13{\rm\ V} {100{\rm k} \over 100{\rm k}+220{\rm k}}.$$

The output is thus the following function of time:

$$V_{\rm OUT}(t) = 1.1687{\rm V} + 0.9781{\rm V} \sin(2\pi 60 {\rm s}^{-1} t),$$ where \$t\$ is in the SI unit of time, i.e. seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Use the principle of superposition to analyze the contribution of each source separately, then add the results together.
Thus, the contribution for the amp at 3.13V is 3.13x100/320=0.978125V;
the contribution for V1 is 1.7x220/320=1.16875V
And the combined result is 1.168750+0.975125=2.146875V

Comment: This is a circuit with both AC and DC components, there's no "combined" DC result as you suggest.